# Edit file while executing in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working on a project in PyCharm that involves extensive computations, with long runtimes.

I would like to do the following: I come up with a version of my code; then run it, then I edit the code some more; however, the run I started before still **only uses the old version of the code** (i.e. the snapshot at the point of running).

Is this possible in PyCharm?

I run my project by selecting the Run 'projectname' option from the Run menu.

I understand the run works by pre-compling the .py files to .pyc files stored in the __pycache__ folder. However, I don't know the following.

1. Will saving the file in PyCharm cause the .pyc files to be replaced by new versions? This is something I want to avoid since I want one run to only use one snapshot of the source tree, not multiple versions at different points of execution.
2. What if some python class is only needed, say, 20 minutes after the run has started. Will the .pyc file be created at the beginning of the run, or on-demand (where the corresponding .py file might already have changed)?

Comment: Unless you're deliberately reloading modules, the `pyc` file is only read once when it is imported. Once the program is running you could delete everything and it would keep running.

Comment: For point 2, I would imagine it depends where you're running the `import foo` command. The state of the file when that is first called would probably be the file it uses rather than the state when the process is started.

Answer (score 1):

I use PyCharm in my classes.  My experience is that the all the required code, including the imported modules, are compiled at runtime.  If you change anything in that suite you need to start running from scratch for it to take effect.

I'm not a professional programmer so my experience is with small apps.  I'd love to hear form an expert.